# Countably many knots

Tags: smooth-manifolds, knot-theory

I think that there are only countably many knots in $S^3$ up to isotopy. How does one prove a statement like this? Similarly, I think it is true that there are countably many smooth structures on a closed manifold up to diffeomorphism. This should follow from the statement for knots and Morse theory.

Comment: Regarding any closed manifold in dimension $3$ (which seems to be the context of your question given your knot-theory tag), it has a *unique* smooth structure up to diffeomorphism. But that's a hard theorem and does not follow from knots and Morse theory.

Answer (score 3):

Every link in $S^3$ has a diagram, and a diagram can be thought of as a $4$-valent planar graph whose vertices are marked with which pair of opposite incident half edges are the understrand.  One can can give the combinatorial data of a diagram (of an unoriented link) by labeling each edge with a distinct integer, then giving a set of $4$-tuples of edge labels, with, say, the first and third labels corresponding to the edges of the understrand.  Countability of links follows.

For closed $3$-manifolds, the [Lickorish-Wallace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lickorish%E2%80%93Wallace_theorem) says that every such manifold is $\pm1$ Dehn surgery on a framed link in $S^3$.  The framing can be encoded via the blackboard framing.  Countability of $3$-manifolds follows.

Alternatively, every closed $3$-manifold has a finite PL triangulation, and the data for such is finite.